# Conditional Compile using Boost type-traits

Tags: c++, boost

I have a template that I would like to conditionally compile depending on the type of the argument.  I only care about differentiating between "Plain Old Data" (POD), i.e., integers, etc or classes/structs.  I'm using c++ VS2008 on Windows.

```
template<T>
class foo
{
    void bar(T do_something){
    #if IS_POD<T>
        do something for simple types
    #else
        do something for classes/structs
    #endif
}}
```

I've been looking at the boost library's and I can see that they appear to have what I want.  However, I do not understand what the correct syntax for the `#if` statement would be.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Edit ---
After reading the responses, I see I overlooked something in my definition of the question.  Class `foo` is a templated class that only needs to instance the version of `bar` that is correct for `class type T`.  I was looking for a solution that can be resolved a compile time.  Hope this clears up my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it without **enable_if**, because all you need is to dispatch depending on type traits. **enable_if** is used to add/remove template instantiations to/from overload resolution. You may want to use call traits to choose the best method to pass objects to your function. As a rule, objects should be passed by reference, whereas POD is passed by value. **call_traits** let's you choose between **const** and **non-const** references. The code below uses **const** reference.

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/call_traits.hpp>

template <typename T>
class foo {
public:
    void bar(typename boost::call_traits<T>::param_type obj) {
        do_something(obj, boost::is_pod<T>());
    }
private:
    void do_something(T obj, const boost::true_type&)
    {
      // do something for POD
    }
    void do_something(const T& obj, const boost::false_type&)
    {
      // do something for classes
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't solve this with the preprocessor, since it doesn't know about C++. (It's a dumb text replacement tool.) Use templates to do this.

Assuming `IsPod<T>::result` returns something alike `Boolean<true>`/`Boolean<false>`:

```
template<T>
class foo
{
    void do_something(T obj, Boolean<true> /*is_pod*/)
    {
      // do something for simple types
    }
    void do_something(T obj, Boolean<false> /*is_pod*/)
    {
      // do something for classes/structs
    }

    void bar(T obj)
    {
       do_something(obj, IsPod<T>::result());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using preprocessor here is not possible.  Have a look at [Boost Enable If library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html) instead.

Specifically, in your case it would look like (not tested):

```
void bar (typename enable_if <is_pod <T>, T>::type do_something)
{
    // if is POD
}

void bar (typename disable_if <is_pod <T>, T>::type do_something)
{
    // if not
}
```

Comment: This will be a compile error, once the class template is instantiated, `T` is fixed, and at that point when you try to call `bar` it will see the two definitions and it will fail to compile one of them. Note that this is not SFINAE, since it will not be a substitution failure --the type is fixed before the instantiation of the member (or so I think, I am never sure with these things :)).